# Any way to open random file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

So I'm making a sudoku game wherein I should get the board of the game from a file (the given numbers) and there should be many files to choose from.

I can only think of is:

```
if choice==1:
    sudoku=open(file1, "r+")
```

and so on but it would take many lines by just opening a file.
Is there a way to open random file in python3?

Comment: You want something like `sudoku = open("file{}".format(choice), 'r+')`?

Comment: use the documentation, this is not a read the documentation for me service.

Comment: You should read the documentation on [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open a file based on user input, you are looking to format strings, using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Let's say the user choice is `choice`, and each file is labeled as `game1`, `game2`, `game3`, etc. That is, the Sudoku game for `choice` is prepended by `game`.

To get the path of the file, you want to use

```
path = "game{number}".format(number = choice)
```

Then, just open it as usual. Putting it all together:

```
choice = int(input("Enter a file number: "))
path = "game{number}".format(number = choice)
sudoku = open(path, "r+")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could theoretically put several filenames into a list, then use the random.choice() method. Here's the code:

```
listOfFiles = [file1, file2, file3]
selectedFile = random.choice(listOfFiles)
```

Then you can load and operate on the randomly chosen file.

Comment: Read more than the question's title.

Comment: If you mean open a file by `load`, that would be a bad choice – you would quickly run out of file descriptors if you had many files. Plus, opening many files, and then picking one out of those, is a lot more expensive than simply picking a random path first and then opening that.

Comment: @RushyPanchal Not what I meant, oops. Answer updated.

Comment: The question is actually not related to random choices. I recommend giving [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) a read.